# Upgrading mongo-java-driver:3.12.14 to mongodb-driver-sync:4.11.1 gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: mongodb, gradle, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to upgrade mongo-java-driver:3.12.14 to mongodb-driver-sync:4.11.1. After making all the necessary changes and resolving compilation errors, i am getting this runtime issue of NoClassDefFoundError.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/internal/diagnostics/logging/Loggers
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.<clinit>(MongoClientImpl.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 212 mofrom re
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.internal.diagnostics.logging.Loggers
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 221 more
```

I had updated the gradle file as follows :

`dependency("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.14")`
changed to
`dependency("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.11.1")`

and made all the necessary code changes to resolve compile time issues. In gradle, the runtime classpath also got updated with proper version.
[runtime classpath in gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trXJX.png)